# How can I freely increase the window I can draw?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I want to increase my drawing window (Java GUI) freely:

[image]

Where do I need to modify the code?
And I want to colorize with RadioButton

This Source code is java SWING, AWT Paint.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new SwingPaint().show();
}

public void show() {
// create mainframe
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("20181567_ ");
    Container content = frame.getContentPane();

// create controls to apply colors and call clear feature
    JPanel controls = new JPanel();

    clearBtn = new JButton("clear");
    clearBtn.addActionListener(actionListener);
    blackBtn = new JRadioButton("black");
    blackBtn.addActionListener(actionListener);
    greenBtn = new JRadioButton("green");
    greenBtn.addActionListener(actionListener);
    redBtn = new JRadioButton("red");
    redBtn.addActionListener(actionListener);
    magentaBtn = new JRadioButton("purple");
    magentaBtn.addActionListener(actionListener);

    blackBtn.setSelected(true);

    ButtonGroup groupRd = new ButtonGroup();

    groupRd.add(blackBtn);
    groupRd.add(greenBtn);
    groupRd.add(redBtn);
    groupRd.add(magentaBtn);
// add to panel
    controls.add(blackBtn);

    controls.add(redBtn);
    controls.add(magentaBtn);
    controls.add(greenBtn);
    controls.add(clearBtn);

// set layout on content pane
    content.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

// add to content pane
    content.add(controls, BorderLayout.NORTH);
// create draw area
    drawArea = new DrawArea();
// add to content pane
    content.add(drawArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
// set container size
    frame.setSize(600, 600);
// can close frame
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
// show the swing paint result
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setResizable(true);
}
```

I think the Layout is the problem.

I can't resize the Paint window.

I used paintComponent in DrawArea().

It's in the package.

Comment: The layout *should* be OK. When there is a limit in the drawing area size, then it's not unlikely that this is caused by the `DrawArea` class. If you post this class (or at least, its `paintComponent` method), one can probably make a guess.

Comment: I used painComponent in the other class(drawing space)
I thisnk the problem is Layout.

Comment: @WONI Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and check [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit] your question to include a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. Explain in detail what the problem is, what the result is you currently get and what result you want instead.

Comment: I tested your code using a JPanel instead of the DrawArea which seemed to work. So I think the problem might be in in the class DrawArea. Could you add the code of this class? Like Progman already sayed a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be good too.

Comment: The problem is NOT the layout. The BorderLayout will always resize the component in the CENTER to fill all the available space in the frame. Your DrawingArea class is probably using a BufferedImage for the custom painting. The BufferedImage will not automatically resize. If you need more help post a proper [mre] that demonstrates the problem. We can't guess what you are doing in the DrawingArea class.